# ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: pip, mpi4py, pyproject.toml

I want to install mpi4py.
The installation fails with the error below.
Please share the solution to the same error.

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 22.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I installed pyproject-toml with "pip install pyproject-toml".
But mpi4py still won't install.
My python version is Python 3.8.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that related packages are twisted.
Installed by following the steps below.

```
apt --fix-broken install
apt install mpich
pip install mpi4py
```

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev
```

Comment: Listen to this guy

Answer (score 4):

conda works:

```
conda install mpi4py
```

Comment: Please just include the final correct answer you tried

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message. I used the Anaconda-Navigator interface and it worked fine.

Another option is to use `brew`. If OpenMPI isn't a dependency issue for you, the installation worked when I used it as well.

```
brew install mpi4py
```

Comment: How will this be used with anaconda or pip packages

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mpich and don't want to install openmpi, but the following worked for me:

```
pip install mpi4py-mpich
```

Answer (score -2):

For me it worked when I used `sudo` before:

```
sudo pip install mpi4py
```

Comment: Installation worked but python shows " no module named 'mpi4py' "

Comment: Yes, it will find no module named mpi4py.  sudo will install it for the admin, not the active user.  You would then have to run sudo's version of python as well, i.e. "sudo python <>.py"  This is not a solution, do not do this.